# Data aggregate/list with d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm a new d3.js user and I struggle to make a basic data conversion.

I would like to move from this format...

```
[
  ["enduser-type","supplier","A","Architecture re"],
  ["enduser-type","customer","A","Architecture re"],
  ["enduser-type","consumer","A","Architecture re"],
  ["enduser-type","supplier","B","System Co"],
  ["enduser-type","customer","B","System Co"],
  ["enduser-type","consumer","B","System Co"]
]
```

... to this one ...

```
[
  ["enduser-type",["supplier", "customer", "consumer"],"A","Architecture re"],
  ["enduser-type",["supplier", "customer", "consumer"],"B","System Co"]
]
```

How can I perform this conversion?

Thank you for your help

Comment: I don't know anything about 3d.js or d3.js or whatever it is, but if it helps, I have been able to achieve this sort of thing with jQuery's `map` function.  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/

Comment: Why the second format?  Unless, you have a specific use case, seems like you should be using a JavaScript object/map.